# How can I display information held in a div's html5 "data" tags in the actual div itself using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div which looks like this:

```
<div class="enemy" data-level="1" data-dmg="10" data-hp="50" data-type="A" data-ready_to_breed="false"><span>Enemy 1</span></div>
```

How can display what is in the data tags in the `<span>` in such a way that the user always has a view into the the state of the div (or "enemy")

Comment: This could have been found out with some googling

Comment: `$('.enemy span').append($('.enemy').data('ready_to_bread'))` ?

Answer (score 5):

To access the `data` property use *[**`.data()`**](http://api.jquery.com/data)*.

```
$('.enemy').data('type'):
$('.enemy').data('ready_to_bread'):
```

and so on.

To display to the `span` about `enemy` try:

```
var enemy = $('.enemy');
$('span', enemy).html(enemy.data('type'))
```

### To display all data properties:

```
var enemy = $('.enemy'),
var data = enemy.data();

$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    enemy.append($('<span/>', {
        'class' : key, // if you need then can add class like this
        html: key + " : " + val + '<br>'
    }));
});
```

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJDEu/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

You could append new elements inside the div like this:

```
$('.enemy').each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
    $this.children().append($('<span />').html('Level: ' + $this.data('level')));
    $this.children().append($('<span />').html('Dmg: ' + $this.data('dmg')));
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZJDEu/

This will result in markup such as:

```
<div class="enemy" data-ready_to_breed="false" data-type="A" data-hp="50" data-dmg="10" data-level="1">
   <span>
   Enemy 1
     <span>Level: 1</span>
     <span>Dmg: 10</span>
   </span>
</div>
```

Of course you could change the jquery to form any markup you wish.

If it were me I would go for something slightly different:

```
$('.enemy').each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
    $this.append($('<span />').addClass('level').html($this.data('level')));
    $this.append($('<span />').addClass('dmg').html($this.data('dmg')));
});
```

which forms the markup:

```
<div class="enemy" data-ready_to_breed="false" data-type="A" data-hp="50" data-dmg="10" data-level="1">
  <span>Enemy 1</span>
  <span class="level">1</span>
  <span class="dmg">10</span>
</div>
```

As this is slightly easier to deal with for styling/layout purpose.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/djdAB/